# How do you properly align right a toolbar in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, toolbar

When you have a toolbar with a few buttons and a drop down, [like this one](https://jsfiddle.net/pupeno/9uym374g/1/):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
        <div class="btn-group"><a class="btn btn-default" role="button" href="">Invite People</a></div>
        <div class="btn-group"><a class="btn btn-default" role="button" href="">Create Campaign</a></div>
        <div class="btn-group"><a class="btn btn-default" role="button" href="">Edit</a></div>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do you properly align it right? I tried pull-right on the toolbar as well as the button groups as well as one button group with pull-right containing all the buttons. None of those worked.

Comment: hope pull-right is working https://jsfiddle.net/9uym374g/2/.. anything else you are expecting?

Comment: the class `Pull-right` should fix your problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right, pull-right at the toolbar level works. I am not sure what made it fail before. Probably I never tried pull-right and one button group per button at the same time (as the whole one button group per button feels silly).

Answer (score 10):

Try like this: **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9uym374g/2/)**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right" role="toolbar">
.....
</div></div>
```

Bootstrap `pull-right` is working fine here.

Comment: this does not work in bootstrap 4, pull right has been changed to float-right

Comment: They changed it again in Bootstrap 5, now it's `float-end`

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 5.3.2, I'm using `justify-content-end` since no other suggestion above works.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/chdaL9k0/1/

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add the class 'pull-right' to .btn-toolbar, or in your css file, just give your toolbar the float right property like so:

```css
.btn-toolbar {
  float: right;
  }
```

Comment: This does not work per se. It will make your toolbar fully float to the right, changing its expected properties. In any case, you could apply the "float: right" to buttons inside a toolbar, overriding the "float:left" property that make them float left.

Comment: You can edit your answer to include this so someone coming after us find the proper response.